# Angular/vsCode: component.html does not auto complete methods/variables from component.ts

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Working through a course at the moment.
Currently if I add a method to servers.component.ts

```
`allowNewServer: boolean = false;`
`...`
`  constructor(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.allowNewServer = true;
    }, 2000)
  };`
```

Then on the servers.component.html I have:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="allowNewServer">Add Server</button>
```

when typing in `allowNewServer` I never get any emmet-y auto-complete options. At least not for the associated value. I DO get abbreviations for a whole host of other options related to Angular but NOT the actual variable.

If I type it in correctly it does recognize it properly and does not error . Ctrl + Click will take me to its definition.

What Have I messed up ?

I've tried to compare the settings with my work machine in the event that it's an extension.

- Current applicable extensions:
- Angular Language Service (from Angular)
- Angular Snippets (Version 13 - John Papa) ((on v15 but did not see one for v15))
- Angular Essentials (Version 13 - John Papa)
- Angular Schematics (Cyrille Tuzi)
- Bunch more of those from Angular Extension Pack (Loiane Groner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what I did here. However, all subsequent projects I have created don't appear to have the issue. I will chalk this up to witchcraft !

Comment: Does not really answer the question.